# Total definition of Gcd in Idris

Tags: idris

I am working in a small project with a goal to give a definition of Gcd which gives the gcd of two numbers along with the proof that the result is correct. But I am unable to give a total definition of Gcd. The definition of Gcd in Idris 1.3.0 is total but uses assert_total to force totality which defeats the purpose of my project. Does someone have a total definition of Gcd which does not use assert_total?

P.S. - My codes are uploaded in  https://github.com/anotherArka/Idris-Number-Theory.git

Comment: I have uploaded one total definition of GCD without using assert_total. But the solution is kind of convoluted, as I have written all the required theory of natural numbers in Idris.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a version which uses the `Accessible` relation to show that the sum of the two numbers you're finding the gcd of gets smaller on every recursive call: https://gist.github.com/edwinb/1907723fbcfce2fde43a380b1faa3d2c#file-gcd-idr-L25

It relies on this, from `Prelude.Wellfounded`:

```
data Accessible : (rel : a -> a -> Type) -> (x : a) -> Type where
     Access : (rec : (y : a) -> rel y x -> Accessible rel y) ->
              Accessible rel x
```

The general idea is that you can make a recursive call by explicitly stating what gets smaller, and providing a proof on each recursive call that it really does get smaller. For `gcd`, it looks like this (`gcdt` for the total version since `gcd` is in the prelude):

```
gcdt : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
gcdt m n with (sizeAccessible (m + n))
  gcdt m Z | acc = m
  gcdt Z n | acc = n
  gcdt (S m) (S n) | (Access rec)
     = if m > n
          then gcdt (minus m n) (S n) | rec _ (minusSmaller_1 _ _)
          else gcdt (S m) (minus n m) | rec _ (minusSmaller_2 _ _)
```

`sizeAccessible` is defined in the prelude and allows you to explicitly state here that it's the sum of the inputs that's getting smaller. The recursive call is smaller than the input because `rec` is an argument of `Access rec`.

If you want to see in a bit more detail what's going on, you can try replacing the `minusSmaller_1` and `minusSmaller_2` calls with holes, to see what you have to prove:

```
gcdt : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
gcdt m n with (sizeAccessible (m + n))
  gcdt m Z | acc = m
  gcdt Z n | acc = n
  gcdt (S m) (S n) | (Access rec)
     = if m > n
          then gcdt (minus m n) (S n) | rec _ ?smaller1
          else gcdt (S m) (minus n m) | rec _ ?smaller2
```

For example:

```
*gcd> :t smaller1
  m : Nat
  n : Nat
  rec : (y : Nat) ->
        LTE (S y) (S (plus m (S n))) -> Accessible Smaller y
--------------------------------------
smaller1 : LTE (S (plus (minus m n) (S n))) (S (plus m (S n)))
```

I don't know of anywhere that documents `Accessible` in much detail, at least for Idris (you might find examples for Coq), but there are more examples in the `base` libraries in `Data.List.Views`, `Data.Vect.Views` and `Data.Nat.Views`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: the implemenation in idris 1.3.0 (and probably 1.2.0) is total, but uses the assert_total function to achieve this.

```
:printdef gcd
gcd : (a : Nat) ->
      (b : Nat) -> {auto ok : NotBothZero a b} -> Nat
gcd a 0 = a
gcd 0 b = b
gcd a (S b) = assert_total (gcd (S b)
                                (modNatNZ a (S b) SIsNotZ))
```

Comment: Does anybody know a total definition without using assert total